# How to run H2O from Zeppelin and working on data node

Tags: h2o, apache-zeppelin

We use H2O over zeppelin(with sparkling water).
Zeppelin works on the edge machine with low resources.
While running H2O from Zeppelin I can see that the Zeppelin interpreter process is doing all the work (I suppose it's the algorithm processing) and takes a lot of resources from the edge node while the data node shows no action.

Is there a way to spread the H2O process to the data node?
Or, in the way H2O is working, can I use spark only to read the data and then process the algorithm on the client?